# No return specified?

Tags: java, loops, return

```
public int removeAll(int i){
    while (head.getData() == i){
        int value = head.getData();
        head = head.getNext();
        return value;
    }
    Node curr = head;
    while (curr.getNext() != null){
        if (curr.getNext().getData() != i){
            int value = curr.getNext().getData();
            curr.setNext(curr.getNext().getNext());
            return value;
        }
        else {
            curr = curr.getNext();
        }

    }

}
```

It keeps saying that there is no return specified for the function cause it's nested and not on the outer loop. How could I bring it out to clear this?

Comment: This will fail to return anything if the last value fails the `curr.getNext().getData() != i` check, so I think the compiler is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this :

```
Node curr = head;
int value = -1;  // change is here
while (curr.getNext() != null){
    if (curr.getNext().getData() != i){
        value = curr.getNext().getData();  // change is here
        curr.setNext(curr.getNext().getNext());
        break;  // change is here
    }
    else {
        curr = curr.getNext();
    }
}
return value;   // change is here
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
public int removeAll(int i) {
    int value = 0; //You can check in caller code like if it is 0 (or put your own value like -1) then do something

    while (head.getData() == i) {
        value = head.getData();
        head = head.getNext();
    }

    Node curr = head;
    while (curr.getNext() != null) {

        if (curr.getNext().getData() != i){
            value = curr.getNext().getData();
            curr.setNext(curr.getNext().getNext());
        }
        else {
            curr = curr.getNext();   //In this part, there is no return code
        }

     }
     return value;
}
```

Since there was at-least one condition which can be satisfied, where there were no return statement, you were getting error. This code should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

What if program control never reaches in any while loop of your `removeAll` method. In this case you are supposed to return an integer value but program never reaches any `return` statement. Because of this compiler is giving you the error.

Add `return` statement at the end of the function.

Answer (score 0):

In compliance with [JLS 8.4.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.7), this program fails to compile because it determines that the method **can** complete normally:

> If a method is declared to have a return type,  then a compile-time
> error occurs if the body of the method can complete normally.

in your case it might be possible for the program to terminate without entering any of the for loops hence without returning anything.